# Conditionally extract numbers from python list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers like

```
20
40
45
60
80
```

That I want to be able to say, for example the average distance between numbers < 50 is 12.5.

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
    for x in f:
        assert x.strip().split()
        positions.append(x)

position_list= []

for x in positions:
    if x < 50:
        position_list.append(x)

print np.mean[position_list]
```

this doesn't work - I think because when I print the positions list I get 20,40,45,60,80 - so I think it is not treating the numbers as individual numbers hence it cannot test if x < 50.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: looks like the data is rather made of lines like:

```
467,1977,3751,4013,5752,6406,6446,7362,7585,8285,8624,8741,‌​9143,9304,11879,1319‌​7,13460,14401,14785,‌​15117,22264,23714,24‌​294,24534,26053,2695‌​9,27714,29462,35342,‌​36538,36612,37031,39‌​093,42281,42967,4394‌​5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, other answers pointed that out, but I feel I should rewrite it for you in a much cleaner way:

```
with open(pos_file) as f:
    positions = [int(x) for line in f for x in line.strip().split(',') if int(x) < 50]

print(sum(positions)/len(positions))
```

- you don't need `numpy` to compute a `mean`, this isn't rocket science
- the `assert` statement is useless. If a line is empty, `split()` returns an empty list, not a problem for the list comprehension.
- the added double loop allows to read several integers located on the same line
- no memory wasted storing numbers when you only want to keep the lowest ones
- took advantage of your feedback on one of the answers to figure out that the list is comma separated. Now I realize that the `csv` module could have been used.

so csv solution:

```
import csv
with open(pos_file) as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    positions = [int(x) for row in cr for x in row if int(x) < 50]

print(sum(positions)/len(positions))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code:

- you do not convert them to an `int` or `float`;
- you use `np.mean[..]` instead of `np.mean(..)` and `np.mean` is not scriptable.

The solution is:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
    for x in f:
        assert x.strip().split()
        positions.append(int(x))

position_list= [x for x in positions if x < 50]

print np.mean(position_list)
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments however, it looks like you feed a comma separated list:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
    for x in f:
        positions += (int(i) for i in x.strip().split())

position_list= [x for x in positions if x < 50]

print np.mean(position_list)
```

Or:

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
    for x in f:
        for i in x.strip().split():
            positions.append(int(i))

position_list= [x for x in positions if x < 50]

print np.mean(position_list)
```

You can also, as @Jean-FrançoisFabre says, use the sum and divide by the number of items, so:

```
from sys import argv
script, pos_file, output = argv
positions = []
with open(pos_file) as f:
    for x in f:
        for i in x.strip().split():
            positions.append(int(i))

position_list= [x for x in positions if x < 50]

print sum(position_list)/len(position_list)
```

In that case you do not have to import [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy).

Comment: I wouldn't use `numpy` only to compute mean. Just do `sum(position_list)/len(position_list)` you don't need any extra module. and what's the use of `assert x.strip().split()` ? (apart from preventing to read `positions` simply in a list comprehension